# Matplotlib (pyplot) savefig outputs blank image I use r.drow()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to save plots (DSR graphs) I make using matplotlib; however, the images are saving blank. The DSR graph is created from r.draw().

Here is my code:

```
import tellurium as te
import pygraphviz as pgv

import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pylab as r


import matplotlib.pylab as r
# Load a model and carry out a simulation generating 100 points
r = te.loada ('S1 -> S2; k1*S1; k1 = 0.1; S1 = 10')
fig = r.draw()

import matplotlib.pylab as fig
fig.gcf()
fig.savefig('DSRgrafic.png', dpi=100)

fig.show()
```

And DSRgrafic.png is blank (also tried with .jpg)

---

I modified the code a little bit, now I use "pyplot" instead of "pylab", but what I get is the same blank image!

```
import tellurium as te
import pygraphviz as pgv

import numpy as np

# Load a model and carry out a simulation generating 100 points
r = te.loada ('S1 -> S2; k1*S1; k1 = 0.1; S1 = 10')
fig = r.draw()

import matplotlib.pyplot as fig
fig.gcf()
fig.savefig('DSRgrafic.png', dpi=100)

fig.show()
```

Comment: Side note: `pylab` is deprecated, use `pyplot`. Then, why are you importing it twice?

Comment: You overwrite `r` after importing

Comment: Hi max, so any solution to correct this overwrite of 'r' ?  Thank you!